# Getting error using CarrierWave with RMagick processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, rmagick

I am using Rails 4, and trying to upload an image and then store it after processing it.

I am using just one view, where I want the user to upload the image, I process the image, store it in db, and then reload the page with the new processed image.

My model (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Uploader (image_uploader.rb)

```
# encoding: utf-8
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::RMagick
storage :file

def store_dir
 "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

process :changeImage

def changeImage
 manipulate! do |source|
   source = source.sepiatone
 end
end
```

Controller (app_main_controller.rb)

```
require 'Rmagick'

class AppMainController < ApplicationController
def index
        # page reload handling when the file uploads
        if(params.has_key?("file-input")) 
            @u= User.new
            @u.image = params["file-input"]
            if(@u.save)
                render js: "alert('SAVED')"
            else
                render js: "alert('Error while saving image! Try Again!')"
            end
         # initial page load
        else
        end
    end
end
```

I access the image-uploader in my view (i.e. index) with `image_tag @u.image_url`

**I keep on getting "stack level too deep"** everytime I add any kind of processing in image_uploader.rb. If no processing is added, the image gets uploaded fine.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: "stack level too deep" usually means you are calling a function recursively without any end recursion condition. So from your code, my guess is `source = source.sepiatone` is somehow triggering process method again which leads into infinite recursion.

Comment: .sepiatone is a method from the RMagick gem, so I suppose there is some problem it.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem. It looks like an issue with the rmagick gem.

**EDIT:
The problem is with case. Try this instead:**

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

**See also [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206350/stack-level-too-deep-when-using-carrierwave-versions) and [this issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1330) or [this issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1205) on github.**

I switched to mini_magick to fix it. (Not ideal, but it's working for me now.)

Uploader class (comment out RMagick):

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'mini_magick'
```

Comment: Actually, I had tried with MiniMagick as well. The resizing works fine. But it starts giving me "NoMethodErrors" for .sepiatone and which ever other methods I use.